# Query xml type column to extract value Oracle database

Tags: xml, oracle

```
<input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" user="ABC" userid="xyz123" xmlns="urn:www.google.com/testsystem">
  <ProcessData>      
    <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear>
  </ProcessData>
</input>
```

I have above example data in xmltype column,  what is the sql query to extract value of userid or user values.  I tried few ways using /input and namespace,  no value returned, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried?  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the default namespace as such. You can tell that is the default because there is no namespace prefix.

```
WITH test_data AS (
    SELECT
        xmltype('<input xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" user="ABC" userid="xyz123" xmlns="urn:www.google.com/testsystem">
  <ProcessData>      
    <reviewYear>2014-2015</reviewYear>
  </ProcessData>
</input>'
) xml_col
    FROM
        dual
) SELECT
    extractvalue(
        xml_col,
        '/input/@user',
        'xmlns="urn:www.google.com/testsystem"'
    ) user_val,
    extractvalue(
        xml_col,
        '/input/@userid',
        'xmlns="urn:www.google.com/testsystem"'
    ) userid_val
FROM
    test_data
```

Comment: Thanks,  this solved my problem,  I was missing @ sign

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can extract attributes using the `XMLTABLE()` function. Be careful with `USER` as a candidate for a column name, since `user` is a reserved word in Oracle. You are much better off using something different for the column name, perhaps `USR` as demonstrated below:

```
select x.usr, x.userid
from   test_data td,
       xmltable('/'
                passing td.xml_str
                columns
                  usr    varchar2(100) path '@user',
                  userid varchar2(80)  path '@userid'
               ) x
;
```

where `test_data` is the name of the table with the XML column `xml_str` (use your actual table and column names, or whatever mechanism to pass the string to `XMLTABLE()`.)